# How to redirect users using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel-5, apache2

I am using Apache on my VM. I have this `.htaccess` right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

## Result

If I do

http://dips.awsri.com/

it works fine.

---

If I do

```
http://www.dips.awsri.com/
```

it redirects me to my log in screen, which I don't want

```
http://www.dips.awsri.com/login
```

How can I stop that ? and instead redirect my user to

```
http://dips.awsri.com/
```

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` config of `www.dips.awsri.com` in question? Did you try testing it from new browsers?